# InDesign script targeting specific text frames

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I have an InDesign document with ~550 pages. On an every page, there are 4 frames. All the pages look the same (see image below). I'm using CS6. I'm new to scripting and a little lost here.

I need some scripts that do some rather basic functions, if possible:

Script 1

- Target text frame (1) (maybe using "pageItem"?)
- Delete the text frame
- Do so on all pages

Script 2

- Target text frame (2)
- Applying a given paragraph style
- Delete all overrides
- Do so on all pages

Script 3

- Target image frame (4)
- Fit Frame Proportionally
- Do so on all pages

[image]

---

I tried the following (see below). Somehow, ID tells me "myParagraph.applyParagraphStyle" is "not a function". Why is that?

Script 2

```
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
myParagraph = myDocument.pages.item(1);
myParagraphStyle  = myDocument.paragraphStyles.item('datum');
myParagraph.applyParagraphStyle(myParagraphStyle,true);
```

Script 3

```
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
var myGraphic = myDocument.pages.item(3);
var myFrame = myGraphic.parent;
myFrame.fit(FitOptions.proportionally);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to answer everything in the original question since the *answer* you posted with the code examples seemed have an actual issue that needed explaining.

I'm also taking a somewhat general approach so that you can use this knowledge to hunt down other things you might need.

---

Looking at the code you posted, you're skipping over a few things. Your variable `myParagraph` points to a page with the index 1, not an item in the page. In other words, you are trying to add the paragraph style to the page.

**This could be a good [reference site for you](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign8)**. It seems to have a search functionality. That said, I personally prefer [this one](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/).

**So to kinda break it down:**

[Pages object](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign8/#Pages.html)

- In this page you can, for example, see that `pages.item()` method "Returns the Page with the specified index or name." and not a `pageItem`, like your code seems to assume.
- So to get a specific page, we could do: `app.activeDocument.pages[0]`. Note that `pages[0]` is equal to `pages.item(0)`. The method `item()` may be confusing to someone who is new to INDD scripting, so decided to use the shorter `pages[0]`.
- This page is littered with green links that lead to the single `page` object. That's where we need to go to find out how to get the items in a page ↓

[Page object](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign8/#Page.html)

- From here we can find `allPageItems` object, with this description: `Lists all page items contained by the Page.`
- There's also `textFrames` object, that we could use if we only needed to find text frames in the page, but perhaps not this time since you want to target other item types too.
- So right now the path we probably would've taken is something like `app.activeDocument.pages[0].allPageItems[0]`.
- You can find out what its type is like this: `alert( app.activeDocument.pages[0].allPageItems[0].constructor.name );`. This is kind of important so you can find out what to do next.
- A little side note:  with `allPageItems` we can get all page items in the page, but you could also for example loop through all items inside a layer and check the page they are on. This could make the script a bit faster if you have like 3000 pages and you know the layer only contains 50-100 items. In which case the difference is looping through 3000 pages or 50-100 items. I wouldn't worry about it though.
- Now to dive into the single `pageItem` object ↓

[PageItem object](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign8/#PageItem.html)

- Good to know: In this page at the bottom under the heading `Object of`, we can find hint towards how to get more specific with the `pageItem`.
- In this case though, if we find out that the pageItem is a textframe using this: `alert( app.activeDocument.pages[0].allPageItems[0].constructor.name );`... We can start figuring out how to access methods and properties that are specific to this item type.
- You could search this page for "TextFrame" and find a link, but you could also use the search functionality to look for `TextFrame`. Either way your next destination is decided ↓

[TextFrame object](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign8/#TextFrame.html)

- Here we can find `TextFrame` specific properties and methods.
- From here we can find `Texts`, which says: `A collection of text objects.`
- Ok, sounds like the right place.
- Now the code would be something like `activeDocument.pages[0].allPageItems[0].texts`
- Moving on ↓

[Texts object](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign8/#Texts.html)

- In here there's a method called `everyItem()`: `Returns every Text in the collection.`. This is probably what we want.
- Then let's dive inside the single `text` object ↓

[Text object](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign8/#Text.html)

- Well well... What do we have here... A method called `applyParagraphStyle()`
- At this point you might be wondering how on earth could anyone even get to this point without someone's guidance. Well, if the starting point is that you want apply a paragraph style and you found out, let's say via googling or perhaps the [Indesign scripting guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/scripting/InDesign_ScriptingGuide_JS.pdf), that there is such a method as `applyParagraphStyle`. The easiest method is to use [the search functionality of the site on `applyParagraphStyle`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzZIH.png). If you do that, one of the results is the `text` object and that's pretty much all the hint you need.

**With all of this combined, we can finally use `applyParagraphStyle` like so:**

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var page1 = doc.pages[0];
var textFrame1 = page1.allPageItems[0];
var text = textFrame1.texts.everyItem();
var datum = doc.paragraphStyles.item('datum');
text.applyParagraphStyle( datum, true );
```

I hope this helps.

---

Just a general reminder that: [Indesign scripting guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/scripting/InDesign_ScriptingGuide_JS.pdf) also has quite a few good examples on how to do this and other things.